# Zend Pagination with array

Tags: php, zend-paginator

I'm currently using [ezSQL](http://justinvincent.com/docs/ezsql/ez_sql_help.htm), which I believe to be a great SQL wrapper.  I've been tasked with adding in pagination that we can just drop in.  Zend [has one](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html), which seems like it should work, as it's loosely coupled with the rest of Zend.  I'm returning an array with ezSQL, ala:

```
$results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM table", ARRAY_A);
```

and then shifting this in to the paginator:

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($results);
```

If I `var_dump($paginator)`, I see the values listed from the query.  However, if I `echo $paginator->pageCount)`, I get `NULL`.  What's the deal?

Unfortunately, switching from ezSQL to Zend_DB is essentially impossible for our group, so that's out of the question.

**EDIT**: Output from `print_r($paginator)`:

```
Zend_Paginator Object
(
    [_cacheEnabled:protected] => 1
    [_adapter:protected] => Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array Object
        (
            [_array:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Doug
                            [last_name] => Lawrence
                            [avatar] => Doug_Lawrence.png
                            [updated_by] => 14306
                            [id] => 413
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-29 12:57:52
                            [publish_date] => 10/29/09
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Jason
                            [last_name] => Lewis
                            [avatar] => Jason.Lewis.jpg
                            [updated_by] => 13547
                            [id] => 411
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-25 09:19:48
                            [publish_date] => 10/25/09
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => David
                            [last_name] => Bowman
                            [avatar] => David_Bowman.png
                            [updated_by] => 13564
                            [id] => 409
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-24 15:13:13
                            [publish_date] => 10/24/09
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => David
                            [last_name] => Bowman
                            [avatar] => David_Bowman.png
                            [updated_by] => 13564
                            [id] => 410
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-24 15:15:48
                            [publish_date] => 10/24/09
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Greg
                            [last_name] => Morris
                            [avatar] => GKMorris.png
                            [updated_by] => 13555
                            [id] => 408
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-24 10:21:14
                            [publish_date] => 10/24/09
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Thom
                            [last_name] => Rainer
                            [avatar] => Thom_Rainer.jpg
                            [updated_by] => 13560
                            [id] => 405
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-23 06:53:43
                            [publish_date] => 10/23/09
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => David
                            [last_name] => Bowman
                            [avatar] => David_Bowman.png
                            [updated_by] => 13564
                            [id] => 406
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-23 16:20:33
                            [publish_date] => 10/23/09
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Tom
                            [last_name] => Harper
                            [avatar] => 1225910432_63
                            [updated_by] => 10843
                            [id] => 402
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-22 11:17:16
                            [publish_date] => 10/22/09
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Jerome
                            [last_name] => Daley
                            [avatar] => Jerome_Daley.png
                            [updated_by] => 13554
                            [id] => 403
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-22 14:06:31
                            [publish_date] => 10/22/09
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Mark
                            [last_name] => Howell
                            [avatar] => Mark_Best.png
                            [updated_by] => 13561
                            [id] => 404
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-22 21:44:51
                            [publish_date] => 10/22/09
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Margaret
                            [last_name] => Marcuson
                            [avatar] => Marcuson.png
                            [updated_by] => 14398
                            [id] => 401
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-21 18:21:55
                            [publish_date] => 10/21/09
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Barry
                            [last_name] => Winders
                            [avatar] => Barry_Winders.png
                            [updated_by] => 13552
                            [id] => 400
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-20 20:08:36
                            [publish_date] => 10/20/09
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Stephen
                            [last_name] => Gray
                            [avatar] => Stephen_Gray.png
                            [updated_by] => 13556
                            [id] => 399
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-20 09:59:16
                            [publish_date] => 10/20/09
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Alan
                            [last_name] => Chandler
                            [avatar] => Alan_Chandler.png
                            [updated_by] => 13549
                            [id] => 398
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-19 12:03:07
                            [publish_date] => 10/19/09
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [first_name] => Mark
                            [last_name] => Howell
                            [avatar] => Mark_Best.png
                            [updated_by] => 13561
                            [id] => 396
                            [title] => 
                            [synopsis] => 
                            [create_date] => 2009-10-17 12:30:16
                            [publish_date] => 10/17/09
                        )

                )

            [_count:protected] => 15
        )

    [_currentItemCount:protected] => 
    [_currentItems:protected] => 
    [_currentPageNumber:protected] => 1
    [_filter:protected] => 
    [_itemCountPerPage:protected] => 5
    [_pageCount:protected] => 3
    [_pageRange:protected] => 10
    [_pages:protected] => 
    [_view:protected] => 
)
```

Comment: what is the paginator results per page set to? how many results do you have? Can you dump a print_r of your variable here (redacting sensitive info of course)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Zak wrote, you are missing

```
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
```

that you can create a view script to render the paginator controls and the items in the paginator.

Than you have to call

```
$paginator->getPages()->pageCount
```

if you are not using Zend_View and it's paginatorControl view helper.

Comment: There are built in defaults for both of those.  And that still doesn't explain why `$paginator->pageCount` returns `NULL`.

Comment: That is because you have to call $paginator->getPages()->pageCount

Comment: Interesting... that bit is only talked about with relation to smarty templates, but apparently, does apply elsewhere.  Points to you sir.