# Pagination from 2 search engines without database

Tags: php

I crawl 2 search engines (google scholar and libra) at the same time to get their datas I am using dom tree parse to get their data and show the result in a result page. but I confused how to make pagination from the two search engine. for the first page, it's easy like :

```
$keystring = isset($_POST['keywords']) ? $_POST['keywords'] : '';
$changeLibra    = str_replace(" ", "%20", $keystring);
$changeGscholar = str_replace(" ", "+"  , $keystring);

$urlLibra   = "http://libra.msra.cn/Search?query=$changeLibra&s=0";
$urlGscholar   = "http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=$changeGscholar&hl=en&btnG=Search&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=on";
//function to get their data using dom tree
getDataLibra($urlLibra);  
getDataGScholar($urlGscholar);
```

the next page of can declare by :

```
$urlGscholar2 = http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=20&q=$changeGscholar&hl=id&as_sdt=0 // page 2
$urlGscholar3 = http://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=30&q=$changeGscholar&hl=id&as_sdt=0 // page 3
```

etc.. and

```
$urlLibra2 = http://libra.msra.cn/Search?query=$changeLibra&s=0&start=11&end=20 // page 2
$urlLibra3 = http://libra.msra.cn/Search?query=$changeLibra&s=0&start=21&end=30 // page 3
```

Any idea how to make that pagination? thank you :)

Comment: I am still unclear on whats the road block in you acquiring pagination. Is there an error? You can always put the results in different array variables to make it work. What exactly is stopping you from getting there?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in array format you can read this [Zend Pagination with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663820/zend-pagination-with-array)

This is the easiest way but you'll need to use Zend Framework library or at least some of the modules.